# Stop shiny::textInput() field from autocapitalizing

Tags: r, shiny, autocorrect

I've run into a small wrinkle with a simple `shiny::textInput()`. The following is a slightly tweaked version of the textInput widget example at https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/widget-gallery.html.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Copy the line below to make a text input box
  textInput("text", label = h3("Text input"), value = ""),

  hr(),
  fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value")))

)


server <- function(input, output) {

  # You can access the value of the widget with input$text, e.g.
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$text })

}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I run this example in the RStudio window, and type a single lowercase letter in the `textInput()` box, an autocorrect tab pops up offering to make it a capital. This is a problem because this field will be used in an SQL lookup that is (usually) a single lowercase letter. It also happened in Safari when clicking the "open in browser" button, until I went in and removed 127.0.0.1 from the list of websites under Autofill | Other Forms. So, not a deal breaker, but I'd like to keep it from happening whenever someone else runs the app. It will only ever run locally, but not always on a Mac.

In researching the question I found that there are HTML attributes for  to turn off auto- whatever, but then I'd have to recreate the whole textInput manually?

**UPDATE:** I just tried it in RStudio (same version) on a PC and there is no autocorrect happening in the RStudio window, or when I move it to Chrome. So I can work around it easily enough.

I am running RStudio 1.0.143 and

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lubridate_1.6.0 shiny_1.0.3     RSQLite_1.1-2  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.11      digest_0.6.12     mime_0.5          R6_2.2.1          xtable_1.8-2     
 [6] jsonlite_1.5      DBI_0.6-1         magrittr_1.5      stringi_1.1.5     DT_0.2           
[11] tools_3.4.0       stringr_1.2.0     htmlwidgets_0.8   httpuv_1.3.3      yaml_2.1.14      
[16] compiler_3.4.0    sourcetools_0.1.6 memoise_1.1.0     htmltools_0.3.6
```

Comment: I think you'd be better off running the input through `tolower` prior to saving to the database. If yu try to control browser settings without exerting control over the browser that wI'll be used, you will drive yourself mad.

Comment: @Benjamin yeah except sometimes there are uppercase letters too. I will try some other browsers b/c I don't recall it happening before moving to os/x

Comment: If you have lowercase and uppercase words in your database, but only want to make specific words lowercase, then you should have a list of specific words (let's call it `L`) to make lowercase, right? Store the `input$text` as it's shown in the browser, then manipulate it in your `server` function, then use the updated text as a variable.

Comment: I'm uncomfortable with solutions where what the user puts in the text box is different from what goes in the database. In some spots I would be able to use a lookup list -- that could populate a "selectize" widget I think.

Comment: same problem while accepting user names for authentication. So is there no solution found to disable auto capitalization?